# GetOracleDecimal Memory Leak

Tags: c#, oracle, memory-leaks

@GilShalit posted t[his comment a year ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340418/please-help-prevent-data-layer-refactoring-of-this-odp-net-code-and-transactions/1340699#1340699):

> "Well, we have come to distrust ODP
>   (.Net 2.0) after fighting a memory
>   leak (in code we supplied to a
>   customer) in GetOracleDecimal for over
>   a year... Good luck!" – GilShalit Aug
>   27 '09 at 12:44

How did you solve it?

We have a service that queries an Oracle database every few minutes that is not releasing memory; after some investigation using WinDbg I discovered that this type is piling up in the finalize queue:  Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OpoDecCtx.

Here's the line that I think is the problem:

```
decimal volume = (decimal)OracleDecimal.SetPrecision(reader.GetOracleDecimal(5), 28);
```

I commented this out and the memory leak disappeared.

Any thoughts will be appreciated - thanks!

Comment: what precisely is your question?

Comment: Why is GetOracleDecimal leaking memory and how can I modify the statement posted to solve the problem?  I was hoping GilShalit would be lurking here and could provide comment but I'm happy to hear from anyone who's run in to this.  Thanks

Comment: There are thousands of questions posted every day, and it doesn't look like Gil is a very frequent visitor.  If you want to attract his attention you need to use the @ symbol, which will show up in his Responses tab.  Like this @GilShalit

Comment: @APC, thanks.  O @GilShalit, where are you?

Comment: Does changing it to this `OracleDecimal.SetPrecision(reader.GetOracleDecimal(5), 28).Value` make any difference  instead of casting it ?

Answer (score 8):

This is an old issue with ODP.NET (see here: [Memory Problems with ODP.NET 10.1.0.4](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=458099) ).

The `OracleDecimal` type holds a reference to an instance of an internal class named `OpoDecCtx`. OpoDecCtx implements `IDisposable` (as it's itself referencing unmanaged memory), but since OracleDecimal does not implement IDisposable, you'll have to wait for the garbage collector to run to free the underlying unmanaged memory. You can check all this using a tool such as .NET Reflector.

Although it's not technically a "physical" memory leak (memory will be eventually freed), it is actually a problem when you're dealing with a large amount of instances of the OracleDecimal type. I don't know why Oracle does not simply implement IDisposable, it's a simple thing to do...

Anyway, I suggest you do some hack job yourself, using reflection:

```
public static class OracleExtentions
{
    public static void Dispose(this OracleDecimal od) // build an extension method
    {
        if (OracleDecimalOpoDecCtx == null)
        {
            // cache the data
            // get the underlying internal field info
            OracleDecimalOpoDecCtx = typeof(OracleDecimal).GetField("m_opoDecCtx", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        }
        IDisposable disposable = OracleDecimalOpoDecCtx.GetValue(od) as IDisposable;
        if (disposable != null)
        {
            disposable.Dispose();
        }
    }

    private static FieldInfo OracleDecimalOpoDecCtx;
}
```

And you would use it like this:

```
OracleDecimal od = reader.GetOracleDecimal(5);
decimal volume = (decimal)OracleDecimal.SetPrecision(od, 28);
od.Dispose();
```

Comment: it is a serious problem in multi threaded applications. AS IN: oraclesi mplementation may kill / block the FINALIZER thread which means NOTHING requiring finalization ever gets cleaned up anymore.

Comment: The solution above functionally works really well, but be careful as it has a quite significant performance impact.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is possible to change from ODP.NET to another provider but we solved this by ditching ODP a long time ago... and are using a 3rd-party (commercial) ADO.NET provider (not affiliated)... check this link out http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/