# Memory leak in Oracle.DataAccess (OraOps11w) when command parameter is OracleDbType.TimeStamp

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net, odp.net

When executing an ADO.NET command that contains `OracleTimeStamp` against an Oracle 11.2.0.3 instance I noticed that the unmanaged Memory grows until the used `OracleConnection` is disposed. So far I've only managed to reproduce this behavior with `OracleTimeStamp`, when using other types (Varchar2,...) everything works as expected.

Here's a sample console application that causes the unmanaged memory to grow until the connection is disposed:

```
internal class MemoryTestOracle
{
    private const string SpTestOracleTimeStamp = "SP_MEM_TEST_TIMESTAMP";
    private const string SpTestOracleTimeStampParam = "P_CONTENT_DATETIMEOFFSET";
    private const int StatementsPerLoop = 1000;
    private const string ConnectionString =
        "Data Source=YOURSERVER;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=YOURUSER;Password=YOURPASSWORD;Pooling=false";

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start connect with {0}", typeof(OracleConnection).Assembly.ToString());
            connection.Open();

            for (int currentLoop = 0; true; currentLoop++)
            {
                OracleTimeStamp[] valuesDateTimeOffset = new OracleTimeStamp[StatementsPerLoop];
                Parallel.For(0, StatementsPerLoop,
                    current => { valuesDateTimeOffset[current] = new OracleTimeStamp(DateTime.Now); });

                Stopwatch stopExecution = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                using (OracleTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    using (OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(SpTestOracleTimeStamp, connection))
                    {
                        command.Transaction = transaction;
                        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        using (OracleParameter timeStampParameter = new OracleParameter())
                        {
                            timeStampParameter.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.TimeStamp;
                            timeStampParameter.Value = valuesDateTimeOffset;
                            timeStampParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                            timeStampParameter.ParameterName = SpTestOracleTimeStampParam;

                            command.Parameters.Add(timeStampParameter);
                            command.ArrayBindCount = valuesDateTimeOffset.Length;
                            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
                    transaction.Commit();
                }
                stopExecution.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("Loop # {0} took {1} ms", currentLoop, stopExecution.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

While testing I used the following storedProcedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_MEM_TEST_TIMESTAMP (
   P_CONTENT_DATETIMEOFFSET TIMESTAMP
   )
IS
BEGIN
   NULL;
END;
/
```

Is this a bug in Oracle.DataAccess (4.112.3.0), the installed Oracle Driver or am I doing something wrong in here (most likely, but I can't figure it out)?

Many thanks for any input!

UPDATE: Added using/disposing to OracleParameter itself. With using OracleParameter as well I think I dispose all disposable objects. The problem still remains.

UPDATE 2: After about 15.000 loops (15.000.000 db executions) the unmanaged memory size is about 150MB; Even if the DateTimeOffset values are created outside the loop (so basically all loops run on the same data) the memory keeps growing (although slower)

UPDATE 3: So far I've tested above code with Oracle's managed Provider as well - no memory problems in there. 
I've also run tests with Devart's ADO provider. In one of their versions (7.*) the problem is exactly the same, in a more recent version it seems fixed.

Comment: There used to be memory leaks pbs with Oracle in .NET back then (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407778/getoracledecimal-memory-leak), but these problems seems fixed. ODP.NET is pretty neat (BTW I have 4.121.1.0). Looking with a tool such as .NET reflector on the OracleTimeStamp class, I don't see anything that could cause a "physical" memory leak. You should try with a tool such as Windbg+SOS to check what's on the heap, GC, etc, or even the new CLRMD: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dougste/archive/2013/05/04/clrmd-net-crash-dump-and-live-process-inspection.aspx

Comment: Linky, have you tried this with ODP.NET 12.1?

Comment: maybe I'm wrong, but you seem to be instantiating a new OracleTimeStamp array each time through the loop (infinitely).  So I can see how this code will leak (with 15k loops anyway)

Comment: @SimonMourier: Many thanks on your link to your answer/solution. Although not sure yet how deep I have to dig until I find the right property/field, but I'm definitely gonna try it.

Comment: @ChristianShay: So far I haven't tried ODP.NET 12.1 yet; I'm gonna set up a virtual machine and run the test with 12.1 client

Comment: @tbone: you're right, the array is recreated in each loop. This could cause the memory to rise until at some point GarbageCollection runs and frees it again. In this situation however GC runs and can't free it, resulting in 4GB memory in above test after about an hour and OutOfMemoryExceptions. Running the code with Oracle.ManagedDataAccess takes about 30MB after 300.000 loops as GC can clean up everything.

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly closing and disposing all of the Oracle objects you are using, including OracleCommand, OracleTransaction, and OracleParameter.

To the managed garbage collector these objects do not seem heavyweight but they may actually be so on the unmanaged side. So the best practice to always close and dispose everything when you are done with it.

Comment: Besides OracleParameter everything already got disposed. I added "using" to OracleParameter as well but the problem remains. 
Nevertheless - thanks for your answer

Comment: I meant to explicitly add it to your code. It is not in the code above. I am not sure if the using clause is sufficient. Try .Close() and .Dispose() explicitly.

Comment: The only object supporting Close is the OracleConnection itself; As on explicitely calling Dispose - don't you think it's enough via using ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx ) ?